# Do lower frequency sound waves penetrate through materials better than high frequency waves

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics

I was doing a physics experiment today where we played different frequencies at the same volume and a sound recorder at the other end with a sheet of cardboard in the middle. We found that the higher frequency tones penetrated through the cardboard better than the low frequency notes sometimes such as 7500hz penetrating better than 300hz. Is this normal or are we not accounting for outside variables? We conducted this in a fairly quiet outside environment in an open area

Comment: How certain are you that the sound you made was at a constant volume?  Since we can't always be sure that the source is constant, we usually use a recorder on both sides of the barrier and take the difference of the levels to get the transmission loss.

Comment: Assuming the source is consistent, you may be in the "stiffness controlled" regime.  For example, see this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395275/why-isolation-increases-with-lower-frequency-in-stiffness-region

Answer (score 0):

How big was the sheet of cardboard, compared to the distance between the sound source and the recorder? remember that sound waves tend to diffract around objects in their path, and that their wavelength affects the diffraction. This is why sound transmission experiments have to be performed with the sound source *inside a box* made of the absorbing material, with the microphone outside the box at a distance from the midpoint of the box of about ~2 box edge lengths.